# Build bundler with Vite (and tree shaking on) __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.exports.shape is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, vite, tree-shaking

I'm working on a UI components library, and I'm bundling with Vite, the goal is to use it like an external library in other repo (with tree shaking on).

When I trying to install it in another existing repo and then run (that runs with webpack) there is on browser console this error:

****WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0**.exports.shape is not a function**

my vite configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    sourcemap: true,
    lib: {
      entry: 'lib/main.js',
      name: 'Components Library',
      fileName: 'web-components',
      formats: ['esm']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react'],
      preserveModules: true,
      output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        globals: {
          react: 'react'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        { src: 'resources', dest: './' },
        { src: 'src/sass', dest: './src' }
      ]
    })
  ]
})
```

Relevant part of package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "module": "dist/web-components.esm.js",
  "sideEffects": [
    "*.css",
    "*.png",
    "*.svg",
    "*.jpg",
    "*.jpeg"
  ],  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "vite build"
    }
 }
```

In various components I have something like:

```
ComponentName.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    label: PropTypes.string,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    isActive: PropTypes.bool,
    onClick: PropTypes.func
  }))
}
```

I tried to remove them in the components sources but the problem persist.

Webpack.config file is too long to show here.